# Installing drivers on Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: raspberry-pi, microsoft-windows-iot

First off, if this is the wrong Stackexchange site, please let me know so I can ask on the correct site.

I'm contemplating installing Windows 10 IoT Core on my Raspberry Pi model 3B+ (so ARM platform) and using it to display a UWP app. Problem is, I need to connect a Fingerprint Scanner to it, which only has 6 pins for UART. Question now is, if I get a USB - UART converter, which drivers do I need to get to install them on my IoT Core?

Answer (score 1):

You should be wiring in the UART directly from the fingerprint scanner to the Raspberry Pi. **Do not try to convert to USB** because then you have an unnecessary device driver problem. There are samples for reading from Serial UART on Windows 10 IoT core that work reasonably well.

Comment: "`There are samples `"... where?

Comment: Also I need to use a USB port, the GPIO pins are occupied by a POE Hat, and I know pass through pins exist but aside from not owning some, I've heard concerns that the GPIO pins could damage my fingerprint scanner